# How to Generate Students Mark sheet

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a little project but had a little problem trying to populate the student marksheet HTML table.

Database design:

```
student table - student_id, name, class_id, section_id
grade - grade_id, grade_name, grade_point, mark_from, mark_upto,comment
subject - subject_id, name, class_id
mark - student_id, class_id, section_id, subject_id, mark_obtained, mark_total
```

The problem is how do I generate a mark sheet table having students, scores, and subject that are particular to a class.
Sample format
[image]

Comment: How does your code look so far?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___